# HTML5 as desktop application using MEAN : Do I have to have full NODE install?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I'm interested in an HTML5 desktop application using MEAN stack.  Do I have to install NODE or is there a compact edition that I can contain only in the application to act with Express as the application only web server?

My desktop of choice is Windows, don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: node-webkit maybe? http://nwjs.io/

Comment: Agree with Kevin B - if I understand the question correctly node-webkit would be a good answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, do you know if these applications must have NODE fully installed or can I put what's needed in the application only? Something like a mini version of node..  I don't want end users to have to install NODE

Comment: So you want to run the MEAN stack as a standalone program without making requests to an external server or for a desktop program to display pages from an external server?

Comment: What I mean is that the web server is local to the application, it is not on another machine, but contained fully in the application.  The application is the webserver, and the content is contained in the application.